# How to make a popup window modal

Tags: java, android, popup

I have a popup window that shows during initial app launch. Here is the code, I used to create the Popup window

```
private void loadPopup(View view, boolean loadSchool){
        Log.i("Started Info","popup");

        //.......

        //create the popup window
        int width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        int height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        boolean focusable = true;
        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(layout, width, height, focusable);

        //Show the popup window
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }
```

This works fine and shows the popup properly. However, if I touch (click) outside the Popup window it gets dismissed. So how can I make this Popup window modal, so that a user have to respond to it before s/he can get back to the other activity?

Answer (score 0):

You can try add the proprety.

```
popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(false);
popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
```

Comment: That did not work for me, and setTouchModal() seems not backwards compatible.  You would think this would be straightforward.  Any updates to this topic?

Answer (score 0):

Try method [`PopupWindow.setTouchModal()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow#setTouchModal(boolean)).